# Filtering ,Adding a columns and inserting null values using LINQ & can we iterate linq n number of times according to our condition?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

This is my Datatable:

```
M N O
x A 5
x B 6 
x A 6 
x B 2 
z C 2 
z C 6
```

This should be the output:

```
M A  B C
x 11 8 0 
z 0  0 8
```

the question regarding iterating query n number of times is i have filtered the datatable and group by the datatable and for instance there is only one value of z so the query will iterate the only once for z but i have to iterate it thrice for other **N** column elements

Code tried So far:

```
From roww In DT.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(h) CStr(h("M"))="x" And CStr(h("N"))=CStr(arr_N_Columns_Items(1)) ).Where(Function(b) (arr_of_str.Contains(CStr(b("N"))))) Group By x=New With {key .idd=roww.Item("M"),key .iddd=roww.Item("N")} Into gg = Group Select gg.OrderBy(Function(l)CStr(l("N"))).Sum(Function(v) (If((CStr(arr_N_Columns_Items(1))=(CStr(v("N"))) ),(CDbl(v("O"))),0) ))
```

the above query does the job but only for all present element and not for absent as described above.I want to do this only using linQ

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: *"i want to do this using linq any suggestions"*. Learn LINQ. SO and similar sites are intended to be to get help with the things that you can't do, not to do the things for you that you don't want try to do.  If you try and fail, then is the time to post a question here.  If you haven't tried then you haven't encountered a specific issue, which is specifically what SO is for.

Comment: @Vickydas added an answer

Comment: hello @jmcilhinney i always try my best than i come to stack i have tried to group by and sum. but cannot get the iteration if the items are less what that mean is if an item has all the items than it works fine but i cannot do it for 0th element i also tried using enumerable.range method to force an iteration this is the code i am working on

Comment: @Vickydas Any code you want to share should be part of your question. Use the edit link and be sure to format as code. It is much too hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Please don't post long code snippets in comments.  They are barely readable when formatted but totally so when unformatted.  Please edit your question and put all the relevant information there, where it should have been to begin with.  It's good that you try your best but it's also important that you write a proper question, which includes what you tried and what happened when you tried it.  You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn better how to ask a good question.

Comment: hey @jmcilhinney do you know how to do it or not ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var result = dataTable.GroupBy(m => m.M).Select(r => 
                new 
               {
                    M = r.Key,
                    A = r.Where(e => e.N == "A").Sum(q => q.O),
                    B = r.Where(e => e.N == "B").Sum(q => q.O),
                    C = r.Where(e => e.N == "C").Sum(q => q.O)
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: hello @GabrielLlorico  i tried this approach but as the N column mai contain many items so this approach would be static as i have to manually type all the items any way of doing this method for n umber of columns ??

Comment: @okay, will change it to something

Comment: hello @gabrielLlorico did you get a way to add dynamic number of columns.......also similar to this question do you know how to add dynamic number of columns while using **Datatable.rows.loaddatarow** or **Datatable.rows.add** methods for instance **DT.Clone.Rows.Add(REST_OF_THE_COLUMNS,OUR_Variable_FROM QUERY)).copytodatatable**